# Windows Server Standard - showing as Windows Vista in Microsoft OS check - What version is it?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

So I became in charge of a Windows Server VM.

I can't tell whether this version is Windows 2003 or 2008.
In My Computer system properties, all it says is:

```
Windows Server Standard
Copyright 2007 Microsoft Corporation.  
Service Pack 2
```

when using this tool:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows/which-operating-system

It says Windows Vista.

command.com shows :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
```

It also seems to have Microsoft Security Eseentials installed - Which I thought wasn't supported on Server OS's.

Comment: try using cmd with "winver", should display version info

Comment: Glad it worked, btw a more detailed version is: systeminfo (not sure if every windows version supports it.

Comment: @MikeH Glad you resolved this. Please be sure to post your solution as an answer and [mark it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you're able.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show a brief version info you could use `cmd` and the command "`winver`"
Or for a detailed version info you could use `cmd` and the command "`systeminfo`".

Comment: *msinfo32* is an even more detailed graphical alternative to *systeminfo*